# Query cached ACL of a directory for a disconnected Windows domain user via Authz API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, acl

I would like to explore the effective rights of a local directory for the currently logged on domain user. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has given me a good starting point and works as expected.

Unfortunately, querying the ACL fails when I disconnect from the domain controller and log on with my cached domain user profile. When being confronted with this environment, the `AuthzInitializeContextFromSid` function in the example code returns `FALSE` and sets `1355 (ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN)` as the last error code:

```
...
PSID pSid = NULL;
BOOL bResult = FALSE;
LUID unusedId = { 0 };
AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE hAuthzClientContext = NULL;

pSid = ConvertNameToBinarySid(lpszUserName);
if (pSid != NULL)
{
    bResult = AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(0,
        pSid,
        hManager,
        NULL,
        unusedId,
        NULL,
        &hAuthzClientContext);
    if (bResult)
    {
        GetAccess(hAuthzClientContext, psd);
        AuthzFreeContext(hAuthzClientContext);
    }
    else
    {
        //prints 1355 as last error code
        wprintf_s(_T("AuthzInitializeContextFromSid failed with %d\n"), GetLastError());
    }
...
}
```

Is it possible to query the (cached) ACL nonetheless? Surely they must be accessible some way or another, even if the domain controller is unreachable.